# Ajax. How to unappend on second click?

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ver").click(function(event){
    var pulsado = $(this).data("dnipass"); 
    alert(pulsado);
    event.preventDefault();
    var prueba ;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'adminVerLineas.php',
        data: {
            dni:$(this).data("dnipass"),
        },
        success: (data) => {
            alert(data); 
            $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').append(data); 
        }

    });    

});
})
```

Its posting data in this html code

```
<?php if($usuarios[$i]["IdRol"] == '2'){ ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                    <!-- -->
                                            <!-- Button -->
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ver"></label>
                                              <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <button data-dnipass="<?= $dni?>" class="ver" name="ver" class="btn btn-primary">Ver líneas</button>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>   
                                        <table id ="<?= $i?>" class="table userInfo" data-formpost="<?= $dni?>"></table> 
                                    </td>

                                </tr>

                            <?php } ?>
```

How do I make that on second click it deletes the data? , and then on third it posts it again, on fourth deletes.... and so..

**EDIT:** Progress using ramraider code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ver").click(function(event){
var pulsado = $(this).data("dnipass");
state = $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').data("state"); //always picking 0, instead of the new generated 1
console.log(state);
state = 1-parseInt(state);

alert(pulsado);
event.preventDefault();
var prueba ;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'adminVerLineas.php',
    data: {
        dni:$(this).data("dnipass"),
    },
    success: (data) => {


         switch( state  ){
                case 1:
                    $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').append( data );
                    $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').attr("data-state","1");

                break;
                case 0:
                    $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').remove();
                    $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').attr("data-state","0");
                break;
            }

    }

});
```

This is how my data-state tag looks on no click

```
<table id="0" class="table userInfo" data-formpost="12345678B" data-state="0"></table>
```

And this is how it looks on first click

```
<table id="0" class="table userInfo" data-formpost="12345678B" data-state="1"></table>
```

And this is how it looks from second click and all of the next ones

```
<table id="0" class="table userInfo" data-formpost="12345678B" data-state="1"></table>
```

It basically stops changing, but im not sure why, seems that `state = $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').data("state");` start to always pick 0, instead the new generated 1

**EDIT 2:**

Ramraiders suggested answer works properly, I was missing that the data-state was moved to button

Comment: do you mean `delete` or `post again` in the `success` callback?

Comment: you can count the number of clicks and then check them for odd and even by `(count%2)` and append and remove the element you want.

Comment: `state = 1 - parseInt( state );` ~ you NEED to set the `data-state` attribute for this to work - set the attribute on the button itself. The button is what gets clicked so it controls what actions are processed. Theoretically you can do like you are but it is more complicated. Your code is greatly different to my version

Comment: @RamRaider not sure I understand, by default data-state is set to 0, and then in each iteration, its being re-set in the switch case. (Altho only works the first 2 times)

Comment: when you say `in each iteration` do you mean when it is `clicked` or when the PHP loop goes to next iteration? I assume the former....

Comment: @RamRaider when it gets clicked

Comment: probably because `$(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').remove();` is removing the element altogether - I would suggest you just clear the contents

Comment: @RamRaider Makes sense. Tried to replace that remove() with empty() , but apparently it doesnt keeps the data, altho detach() should keep it, but still not working.

Comment: see update to answer below for how I got it to work ( as I think you intended )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203163/discussion-between-ramraider-and-mouchin777).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `dataset` attribute ( on the button ) that you toggle between 1 and 0 - the value can then be used to fork the logic in your ajax function. For example, set `data-state=0` and then toggle it's value in the `click` handler and test that value in the callback

```
<button data-dnipass='<?php echo $dni;?>' data-state=0 class="ver" name="ver" class="btn btn-primary">Ver líneas</button>
<!-- note the data-state attribute that will be toggled! -->


$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".ver" ).click( function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        event.target.dataset.state = 1 - event.target.dataset.state;
        var pulsado = $(this).data("dnipass"); 

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'adminVerLineas.php',
            data: {
                dni:pulsado
            },
            success: (data) => {
                switch( parseInt( event.target.dataset.state ) ){
                    case 1:
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').append( data ); 
                    break;
                    case 0:
                        /* delete */
                    break;
                }

            }
        });
    });
})
```

I don't use jQuery so I am not familiar at all with its syntax or intricacies but this appears to do what you want. I have put it together into a working demo - obviously some of the code you see is `mickey mouse` but should give the idea.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();
        echo "gigantic mouse strangles elephant";
        exit();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>jQuery-toggle append/delete</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $( ".ver" ).click( function(event){

                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.target.dataset.state = 1 - event.target.dataset.state;
                    var pulsado = $(this).data("dnipass"); 

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: location.href, //'adminVerLineas.php',
                        data: {
                            dni:pulsado
                        },
                        success: (data) => {
                            switch( parseInt( event.target.dataset.state ) ){
                                case 1:
                                    $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').append( data ); 
                                break;
                                case 0:
                                    /* delete */
                                    $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').text('');
                                    /* or, slightly better IMO */
                                    // $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').html('<tr><td></td></tr>');
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    });
                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ver"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <button data-state=0 data-dnipass="BANANA APPLE ORANGE STRAWBERRY" class="ver" name="ver" class="btn btn-primary">Ver líneas</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                    <table id ="XYZABC123" class="table userInfo" data-formpost="BANANA APPLE ORANGE STRAWBERRY"></table> 
                </td>
            </tr>


        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So far i've been trying your code, but there seem to be an issue in my implementation, can you check it? it changes the data for the first time, but then it gest stuck there and doesnt change it anymore

Comment: thanks, i was missing that your data-state attribute was in the button, now it works

Answer (score 1):

Create two click handler such as:

```
$(".ver-post").click(function(event) {...}
```

and

```
$(".ver-delete").click(function(event) {...}
```

in the success of each replace the class.

```
success: (data) => {
        ...
        $(this).addClass('ver-delete').removeClass('ver-post');
    }
```

Haven't tested it yet but something like this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Like @urfusion mention it, counter is probably the easiest solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    count_click = 0; // new row counter
    $(".ver").click(function(event){
        count_click += 1; // new row update counter
        var pulsado = $(this).data("dnipass");
        alert(pulsado);
        event.preventDefault();
        var prueba ;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'adminVerLineas.php',
            data: {
                dni:$(this).data("dnipass"),
            },
            success: (data) => {
                alert(data);
                if (count_click % 2 == 0) { // second, fourth, sixth...
                    // TO DO - delete data
                } else { // first, third...
                    // TO DO - add data
                }
                $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').append(data);
            }

        });
    });
})
```